# Best C# idiom to convert the items on an object array to a string?

Tags: c#, .net, converting

I have something akin to

```
object[] values = getValues();
string renderedValues = string.Join("-", 
                          Array.ConvertAll<object,string>(values,
                          new Converter<object,string>(o2s)
                        ));
```

where `o2s` is

```
public static string o2s(object o) { return o.ToString(); }
```

Comments welcome!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There exists a method for that conversion already:

```
string renderedValues = string.Join(
  "-",
  Array.ConvertAll<object, string>(values, Convert.ToString)
);
```

---

#### Update:

In framework 4 an overload that takes an object array was added, so it will do the conversion for you:

```
string renderedValues = string.Join("-", values);
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to create a new `Converter`. Also, I'd rename the variable:

```
object[] values = getValues();
string joinedValues = string.Join("-", Array.ConvertAll<object,string>(values, o2s));
```

Comment: what is `o2s` ?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer: It's the function Vinko declares in the second half of the question.

Comment: Gotcha - for some reason my eyes didn't see that when I first read it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not <del>Zoidberg</del> simply this?

```
string renderedValues = string.Join("-", getValues());
```

Simply using the `Join(string separator, params Object[] values)` overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx

Comment: This overload an addition on 4 and I'm targeting 3.5

Comment: Any idea how the two patterns compare from a performance standpoint. (*Just assume .NET 4 was an option*)

Comment: No idea whatsoever. Do you see any reason to spend time making code more complicated and less straightforward than it needs to be?